# Apt-get hangs at first repo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-12.04

When I perform an `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get update`, I notice that it can take almost a minute when connecting to a repo.

For example, when doing a `aot-get upgrade`, it will be stuck for about a minute at

```
Get:1 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main
```

before speeding through the rest of the process.

```
Get:1 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libcurl4-gnutls-dev amd64 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.1 [1,065 kB]
Get:2 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.1 [227 kB]
Get:3 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libcurl3 amd64 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.1 [236 kB]
Get:4 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main curl amd64 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.1 [137 kB]
Fetched 1,665 kB in 1min 3s (26.3 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 41481 files and directories currently installed.)
```

Is this normal? If not, how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Try another mirror.

Comment: Perform a tcpdump at the same time.  Do you see any long DNS timeouts, or any http timeouts?  Do you see any outgoing requests that are not getting answered?  Is your system trying to use IPv6 or something, but you don't have that properly setup?  Anyway, my point is, that your problem is almost certainly something about your network, that you should be able to find with some simple inspection using the correct tools.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to know exactly what is going wrong.

Try changing your dns servers in /etc/resolv.conf to something else to see if that solves the problem. You can use opendns servers instead of what is already in your /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Opendns
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Or Google's dns servers:

```
# Google's dns servers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

DNS may or may not be the problem, but it won't hurt to try and see if it resolves your problem.